# Angular Router - intercept child route change

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ng-zorro-antd

I'm using NG-ZORRO for the UI components, and I've got this template

`my-component.component.html` (`MyComponent` class)

```
<nz-tabset [nzSelectedIndex]="selectedIndex">
  <nz-tab [nzTitle]="titleTpl">
    <ng-template #titleTpl>
      <div [routerLink]="['routeOne']"><i nz-icon type="profile"></i>...</div>
    </ng-template>
  </nz-tab>
  <nz-tab [nzTitle]="docsTpl">
    <ng-template #docsTpl>
      <div [routerLink]="['routeTwo']"><i nz-icon type="file-text"></i>...</div>
    </ng-template>
  </nz-tab>
</nz-tabset>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I need to change `selectedIndex` based on the active route, be it `routeOne` or `routeTwo`.
A mapping might be

```
{
   "routeOne": 0,
   "routeTwo": 1
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot use `routerLinkActive` as `nz-tab` doesn't support routing.

Routes are

```
export const MY_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':myParam',
    component: MyComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'routeOne',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'routeOne',
        component: RouteOneComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'routeTwo',
        component: RouteTwoComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

All of that because a user might want to access directly `http://.../123/routeOne`, so I need to pre-select the right tab.

Can I accomplish this in some way? Maybe using `ActivatedRoute` or `Router`?

Comment: You just want to add a css class when the user is navigating `routeOne` or `routeTwo`?

Comment: @AndrewRadulescu see my current solution down here, it will make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the router to listen for the events as you did:

```
this.selectedRoute$ = this.router.events.pipe(
     startWith(this.router),
     filter(
         (event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof Router
     ),
     map((event: NavigationEnd | Router) => event.url),
     map(path => this.map[path])
);
```

You can adapt the later map to check if the route matches your route and then subscribe using the async pipe in the template like:

```
<nz-tabset [nzSelectedIndex]="selectedRoute$ | async">
....
</nz-tabset>
```

This will also work when you refresh the page or navigate manually to that route.

**Edit:** or subscribe to `ActivatedRoute` to retrieve the URL in the same manner. Make more use of the Observables, cool stuff! 
Good luck!

**Edit 2:** If you want the route only for the current `<router-outlet>` scope you can make use of the `ActivatedRoute` like this:

```
this.router.events
            .pipe(
                filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
                map(() => this.activated),
                map((route) => {
                    while (route.firstChild) {
                        route = route.firstChild;
                    }
                    return route;
                }),
                switchMap((route) => route.url)
            )
            .subscribe((url) => console.log(url));
```

This should give you what you need.

Comment: The problem is this way the `event.url` comes in as `/.../123/routeTwo` for example, so I'd have to split it and take only the last one?

Comment: Of course, map it and retrieve only the last part that you need. You can reuse this everywhere in the app where you need the URL (full or part of it).

Comment: Another problem might be if I have child routes of `routeOne` or `routeTwo`, then the last part won't be the right one anymore. Is my assumption correct? I think about that because router's events are application wide.

Comment: Yes, but you can check if the route is present in the URL making it more dynamic, instead of splitting and getting the last piece.

Comment: Thanks for the update! What is `this.activated`? `ActivatedRoute`?

Comment: Yes ` constructor(private activated: ActivatedRoute) {}`

Comment: Okay, give me a moment to understand the `while` loop logic.

Comment: Use the debugger. Starting from the root for the current `<router-outler>` will go to the last child and get the URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192108/discussion-between-andrew-radulescu-and-lppedd).